# Window.location.reload() on specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form on my personal page, when you submit it, I call JS function to reload page and show alter box.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
  if (reloading) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
      sended();
  }


function reloadP() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    window.location.reload();
}
function sended(){
$('#alterbox').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow').hide(0);
}
```

Problem is, that page reloads and shows header, but contact form is way too below, on the bottom of the page. Can I reload page to stay on same place?

Comment: post relevant html code or snippet will help us to understand the problem.

Comment: Why are you reloading the page in the first place?

Comment: Because of contact form in simple php.

Answer (score 2):

Before reload you can save scroll position in sessionStorage, too.
And then after reload get it,  and scroll your page to them.

Before reload:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("scroll", window.pageYOffset);
```

After reload:

```
const scrollBy = sessionStorage.getItem("scroll")    
if (scrollBy) {
 window.scrollTo(scrollBy,0)
}
```

Comment: That's it! I just changed (scrollBy,0) to (0,scrollBy), because that would be horizontal scroll. Thanks a lot