# How to ? (1) after scrolling a webpage to the top (2) then automatically reload a page

Tags: javascript, html

What's the html javascript code for after scrolling a webpage to the top then automatically reload a page (not the other way around). Thank you!

Comment: html is the language used to describe documents on the web. JavaScript is a programming language. Might be time to revisit the basics.[html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48163408/18001301) answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onscroll = () => {
    if(scrollY === 0){
    location.reload()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to use js to click a link.
Say that on the top of the page you have a div with id of top:

```html
<div id="top">top section of page</div>
```

Then all you need to do in js is just to click on a virtual anchor element:

```js
let a = document.createElement("a")
a.href = "#top"
a.click()
```

Then just call `window.location.reload()` to reload the page

**I haven't tested this but the main idea works**

Answer (score 0):

```
function topScrollAndRefresh() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.reload()
  })
}
```